# Passing global envvar JAVA_HOME to builds through jenkins.war

Tags: linux, jenkins

I administrate a jenkins instance on Linux.
I have been asked to pass a system-wide **JAVA_HOME** as a global ENV var for jenkins **builds** (as opposed to just jenkins itself), and I wish to do this **through the service/daemon startup script**. (Please don't give per-job `Jenkinsfile` / build pipeline solutions.)

Some plugins like `maven-javadoc-plugin` apparently require this variable.
(Curiously, this was never before necessary for the existing builds on this jenkins install. Either the used plugins changed, or jenkins did? Since I don't build on this, I can't say which.)

The only way I managed to do make this work for now, is using a fixed string through the GUI at `<jenkins-url>/configure` under "Global properties > Environment variables".
I understand I can add JDK installations under `<jenkins-url>/configureTools/`, but this, again, only allows fixed strings, which I can't be bothered to remember correcting on every system update.

What I should be able to do instead, is pass the ENV var to the jenkins service at startup, such as: `JAVA_HOME=$(dirname $(dirname $(readlink -f $(which java))))`.

jenkins (debian package) in fact brings an [`/etc/default/jenkins` file](https://gist.github.com/p-l/6028928),
which says you can pass a `--javahome=$JAVA_HOME` argument; like this:
`/usr/bin/java -jar jenkins.war --javahome=/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64`

However, this seems incorrect and *does not work* on current jenkins versions. It throws `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unrecognized option: --javahome=/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64 at winstone.cmdline.CmdLineParser.parse(CmdLineParser.java:52)`

Since some other options uses camelCase (like `--httpPort`), I have also tried `--javaHome=$JAVA_HOME` instead.
This option is accepted (jenkins doesn't choke on startup), but it also doesn't work, it appears to get ignored?
I didn't manage to figure out if this *should* be the correct option from the [source code](https://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkins) either.
Jenkins version: 2.319

Perhaps someone can tell me if this used to work, is a bug, or how to do this if I'm doing it wrong.

Comment: That is not the preferred approach Jenkins is structured for. The Java Jenkins is launched under should be independent of whatever your jobs/builds/applications are dependent on. Most basic case: launch Java on a Win node from Linux master, there's no `/usr/lib/...`, fail. Or, Oracle Java for jobs license may be a violation if run for a non-Oracle product (ie Jenkins). The intent of Jenkins is Java for controller, Java for nodes, and Java for jobs (which could vary per job) should all be independent.

Comment: @IanW, indeed. The JAVA_HOME for the builds is not necessarily the same as jenkins'. The issue is passing the correct path through from the system, instead of hardcoding it in the GUI or jobs, because as you said: it could be different on a win node than on a linux node, after updates, etc. Also, side-loading/installing JDKs through Jenkins is to be avoided for maintenance as much as security reasons (timely security updates are platform managed).